# PHP Database serialized array issue

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, serialization

Got an issue when inserting a blank serialized array into the database. I'm using wordpress (just for full disclosure, shouldn't make a difference) and using the `add_post_meta()` function to input some additional information. Here's a snippet:

```
add_post_meta($post_id, 'information', serialize(array()));
```

The serialized array is intentionally blank for the moment. Anyway here's the expected/actuals:

```
// Expected value 
a:0:{}

// Actual value
s:6:"a:0:{}";
```

Any help?

Comment: Try reading this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta

Comment: Your `s:6` comes from this - `a:0:{}`, a string that is 6 characters long. I believe you don't need to serialize array data with `add_post_meta()`. You could also try `maybe_serialize();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add post meta auto-serializes arrays. And also get post meta, pass TRUE at the last argument: like get_post_meta($post_id, 'information', TRUE);

More details here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta

Comment: Thanks for that. It seems that you don't need to serialize the data for add_post_meta as it does it for you if you input an array. Therefore my problem was that my data was double serialized.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue but I could used `add_post_meta($post_id, 'information', array());`  instead of `add_post_meta($post_id, 'information', serialize(array()));`
try it you can resolve your issue..